# How to include external html file and js file in polymer 3?

Tags: javascript, html, web, polymer, components

I am trying to separate html part from .js in polymer 3.0 .
How can I include external html file in .js ?
OR
how can I separate them ?

```js
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
/**
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 */
class InfyAssign extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    
    }
  </style>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
      Hello
  </div>
    <div>
      <img src="../../images/image1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
 
    `;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would not recommend you to separate the html part to another file. If you feel your component is too large, just separate it to another component instead.

Because of it's a javascript file (ES6 Modules) so it cannot import html directly but you can separate `template` function to another file and import it.

index.html

```
<my-app></my-app>
<script type='module' src='app.js'></script>
```

app.js

```
import { PolymerElement } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js'
import home from './home.js'

class App extends PolymerElement {
  static get properties () {
    return {
      count: Number
    }
  }

  static get template () {
    return home()
  }

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.count = 0
  }

  increaseCount () {
    this.count += 1
  }
}

customElements.define('my-app', App)
```

home.js

```
import { html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js'

export default function () {
  return html`
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <h2>Count: {{count}}</h2>
    <button on-click='increaseCount'>Increase</button>
  `
}
```

If you want a real html file. You can use `fetch` to download html file and parse it as a `template` function.

app.js

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js'

class App extends PolymerElement {
  static get properties () {
    return {
      count: Number
    }
  }

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.count = 0
  }

  increaseCount () {
    this.count += 1
  }
}

fetch('home.html')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    Object.defineProperty(App, 'template', {
      get: function () {
        return eval(`html\`${text}\``)
      }
    })
    customElements.define('my-app', App)
  })
```

home.html

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<h2>Count: {{count}}</h2>
<button on-click='increaseCount'>Increase</button>
```

Or you can use a bundle library like Webpack which allowed you to import html file (through loader) into your javascript file.

See [polymer-skeleton](https://github.com/PolymerX/polymer-skeleton) and this [article](https://codeburst.io/polymer-skeleton-webpack-postcss-service-workers-and-the-future-50189fbea23f).